# Get all photos from all albums

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

I've got this code to get photos from a specific album, however I want to ask for all albums, get their id's and for each id list all the pictures.

```
<?php 
 require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
  $appId = '[app_id]';
  $secret = '[app_secret]';
  $access_token = '[access_token]';
  $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => $appId, 'secret' => $secret, ));
  $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);



$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums?fields=name,count'); 
print_r ($albums);


$album_ID = "309608592385363"; //album ID
$list_pictures = $facebook->api('/'.$album_ID.'/photos', array('access_token' => $access_token));
print_r ($list_pictures);



?>
```

Bare in mind I removed variable like my app id, etc. They do work each on their own accord, by printing $albums and $list_pictures but I'm trying to bridge the gap between them so that albums tells list pictures each album_id to access. I'm doing this for a client who isn't going to getting into the hand coding.

THANKS!

Comment: This question also titled: "Things Facebook probably doesn't want you to do..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  $albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums?fields=id'); 
  $pictures = array();
  foreach ($albums['data'] as $album) {
    $pics = $facebook->api('/'.$album['id'].'/photos?fields=source,picture');
    $pictures[$album['id']] = $pics['data'];
  }

  //display the pictures url
  foreach ($pictures as $album) {
    //Inside each album
    foreach ($album as $image) {
      $output .= $image['source'] . '<br />';
    }
  }
  exit($output);
```

Comment: This is probably it but I don't know where to put it in my code. :/ I think i might be a little in over my head.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve? get image urls or you need to group them by albums?

Comment: I want to to get photos(image urls) clustered by albums.

I tried putting the code you suggested where I thought it went in the code I posted with the question but I didn't work.

Comment: I edited the sample. Place it below print_r($albums) and then check what print_r($pictures) is holding

Comment: Okay, I did that, but it is only printing $albums, after that it doesn't print pictures. I echoed two line breaks before the print $pictures and after that it's blank. my testing page: http://www.tiffanyisrael.com/profiles.php

even if it doesn't work thanks for you help so far!

Comment: I reworked it. This should be the complete code after you get the access token. (tested and worked) Btw, I think you're doing it wrong with access token but that's another story :)

Comment: It doesn't separate them into albums but it works! Thanks! :)

Comment: They are :) Added a comment for this

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you loop over the $albums array?

pseudocode:

```
foreach $album in $albums
{
  $list_pictures += $facebook->api(...);
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm a newb' to start. :)

So I put the code in that you suggested after $albums = $facebook->... and I get a syntax error in Dreamweaver. I moved it around in the code and I still doesn't work. When I test it on the server it shows a blank screen. :/

Comment: @OUHSDWebmaster it was just pseudo-code, meaning, it wasn't actually supposed to be grammatically correct.  See here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php for more info and to LEARN :)